# Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have seen in many places that to access nested documents and collections the pattern is something like `db.collection("users").doc("frank").collection("pets")` etc.

This makes a lot of sense to me and is easy to understand. The trouble is, my (React) project is set up in the *Web version 9* way. I've combed the docs over and over and can't see anything that goes beyond referencing X doc in Y collection.

I need to reference Users > uid > someCollection

But in the *Web Version 9* way I can only do: `doc(db, "users", uid)`

How do I go deeper?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are trying to get:

- a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference), then use `collection()`:

```
const myCol = collection(db, "collection", "doc1", "sub-col1")
```

- a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference), then use `doc()`:

```
const myDoc = doc(db, "collection", "doc1", "sub-col1", "sub-doc1")
```

The concept remains same. The path to a document has *even* number of segments e.g. `col/doc/sub-col/sub-doc` while path to a collection has *odd* e.g. `col/doc/sub-col`.

*Both the methods will throw an error if invalid number of parameters are passed.*

---

In the name-spaced version (v8), it used to look like:

```js
// DocumentReference
firebase.firestore().doc("col/doc/sub-col/sub-doc")

// CollectionReference
firebase.firestore().collection("col/doc/sub-col")
```

In essence, you keep adding path segments to the same `doc()` or `collection()` methods.

```js
doc(firestore: Firestore, path: string, ...pathSegments: string[]):
// You can also use spread operator with an array
```

---

An example with spread operator:

```js
const myDocPath = "users/user1/posts/post1/comments/comment1"
const docRef = doc(db, ...myDocPath.split("/"))
```

Just make sure you don't have any leading or trailing slash if using `spread operator` with `split()`.

Comment: That's it! I was trying things like that, but just wasn't doing quite the right combination of things. Thank you so much, huge breakthrough in my project <3

Comment: I just saw your edit, that extra part with the spread operator is really cool and will definitely come in handy! 