# How to create a custom id document in firestore(Firebase modular SDK (v9))

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can we create a document with a custom id in firestore with the new modular SDK V9?

```
const register = async function (adminEmail){
  try{
    const docSnap = await getDoc(availableIdRef);
    const collegeId = docSnap.data().id; //This should be the document id

    const adminRef = collection(firestore, 'admin');
    await addDoc(adminRef, {adminEmail, collegeId});

  }catch(e){
    alert("Error!");
  }
}
```

I want to create a new document with id as `collegeId` in `admin` collection.

I know how to do this in web version 8(namespaced) but have no idea about web version 9(modular).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setDoc()` method to specify an ID instead of `addDoc` which will generates a random ID as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document):

```
const adminRef = doc(firestore, 'admin', collegeId);
//       doc  --->^
await setDoc(adminRef, {email: adminEmail, id: collegeId}) // overwrites the doc if it already exists
//    ^^^
```

Also note that to create a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) you need to use `doc()` and not `collection()` which is used to create a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference). I've explained difference in these 2 here: [Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9/68987445#68987445)