# Firebase 9 - How to do new doc ref

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Hello guys i've been trying to convert this code into modular firebase 9:

fb8:
`const userRef = db.collection('Users').doc();`

to
fb9:
`const userRef = doc(db, 'Users');`

But i'm getting this error:
`FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but Users has 1.`

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `doc()` method is equivalent to `.collection('users').doc('docID')` where you need to specify the ID. If you are trying to add a document with random ID then you add use `addDoc()` with `collection()` as shown below:

```
const usersCol = collection(db, 'Users')

await addDoc(usersCol, {...data})
```

---

If you want the random ID before adding the document then you can try this:

```
const userRef = doc(collection(db, 'Users'));
console.log(userRef.id)
```

> Document references must have an even number of segments, but Users has 1.

You can checkout this answer for explanation of `doc()` and `collection()`:

[Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9)

Comment: but i need to grab the id first before adding it, guess i will just use the old method. thanks man :D

Comment: @JonathanJeshuaLaniba the 2nd method does not create a document but you get a reference for it and hence get the ID as shown.

Comment: thank you for helping me :D
i was not able to make it work with the new logic, i did use the old one thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Expanding @Dharmaraj answer:

- Get a docRef with a random `id`
- Use the `id` before the document creation, for example, insert the `id` in the document data
- Then create the document

```js
const usersRef = collection(db,'users') // collectionRef
const userRef = doc(usersRef) // docRef
const id = userRef.id // a docRef has an id property
const userData = {id, ...} // insert the id among the data
await setDoc(userRef,userData) // create the document
```