# Firebase configuration 2022

Tags: javascript, firebase, configuration

I am coding along on a FB clone tutorial. The issue is that I'm doing it in 2022, so a lot of updates need to be implemented. I'm really new to firebase, so i do need some help on this.

my firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/storage';

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDNCuXEn5todyFVWl6CLJaNridOkTxLi1o",
    authDomain: "fbclone-b8dca.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "fbclone-b8dca",
    storageBucket: "fbclone-b8dca.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "366781998977",
    appId: "1:366781998977:web:84791acf7d270c5fdbaa80"
};

// // Initialize Firebase
// const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const app = !fireBase.apps.length ? fireBase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : fireBase.app;

const db = app.firestore();

const storage = fireBase.storage();

export {db, storage}
```

my inputbox.js

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import Image from "next/image"
import { CameraIcon, EmojiHappyIcon, VideoCameraIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import {useRef} from 'react'
import {db, storage} from '../fireBase';

const InputBox = () => {
    const {data: session} = useSession();
    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    const sendPost = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!inputRef.current.value) return;

        db.collection("posts").add({
                message: inputRef.current.value,
                name: session.user.name,
                email: session.user.email,
                image: session.user.image,
                timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            })

        inputRef.current.value = ""
    }
```

this is the error that i get:

```
./fireBase.js:1:0
Module not found: Package path . is not exported from package /home/alondrob/code/labs/projects/fbclone/node_modules/firebase (see exports field in /home/alondrob/code/labs/projects/fbclone/node_modules/firebase/package.json)
> 1 | import firebase from 'firebase';
  2 | import 'firebase/storage';
  3 | 
  4 | // Your web app's Firebase configuration

Import trace for requested module:
./components/InputBox.js
./components/Feed.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

I know the import syntax  has changed and i tried few things like

```
// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
  authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
  projectId: '### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###'
});

const db = getFirestore();
```

I just not sure how to configure it all together.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting from an outdated tutorial, consider starting from the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) or [codelab](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web). They are fully up to date with the latest changes.

While the latest SDKs may have a different syntax, the older SDKs continue to work just fine. So if you work from an outdated tutorial/resource, you can always use the SDK version that the tutorial is based on. You can also [use the latest SDK in compat mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat), by following the instructions in the upgrade guide.

Answer (score 0):

***Your are dealing with firebase version 8 code base and trying to import your local `firbase.js` component inside `inbox.js` component***

**Issue:** you must have install firebase without specifying the version as **version 8,** which means you have install the latest version of firebase, **version 9 instead of version 8.**

As such you must refactor the code inside `firebase.js` component as below.

```
 import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
    import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyDNCuXEn5todyFVWl6CLJaNridOkTxLi1o",
      authDomain: "fbclone-b8dca.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "fbclone-b8dca",
      storageBucket: "fbclone-b8dca.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "366781998977",
      appId: "1:366781998977:web:84791acf7d270c5fdbaa80"
    };
    
   
    const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : 
    getApp();
    
    const db = getFirestore(app);
    const storage = getStorage(app);
    
export default {db, storage};
```

**Though, the solution above will solve your issue but one more will result from `inputbox.js`**.
So inside `inputbox.js` component code, refactor how you are fetchig data from firebase [follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9#68987445) for that

Refactor this

```
db.collection("posts").add({
                message: inputRef.current.value,
                name: session.user.name,
                email: session.user.email,
                image: session.user.image,
                timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            })
```