# is there any way to find a document from firebase firestore with the query of where

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of tokens in which each document create with auto id but I store a tokenId in the document and now I want to search a single document which has specific tokenId
How can I implement where query in my this code

```
const docRef = doc(db , "tokens")
const data= await getDoc(docRef);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use [`collection()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#collection) instead of [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#doc) to create a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference). Then you can build the required [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query) using [`query()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#query) with `where()` as shown below:

```
import { collection, getDocs, query, where } from "firebase/firestore"

const colRef = collection(db , "tokens")

const qSnap = await getDocs(query(colRef, where("tokenId", "==", "TOKEN_VALUE")));

if (qSnap.size) {
  const data = qSnap.docs[0].data();
} else {
  console.log("No token found")
}
```

Also checkout:

- [Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9/68987445#68987445)
- [Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Comment: its not working still unable to get data
however qSnap gives me a firestore document in the form of Vh object i am unable to populate data from it

Comment: @UsamaSaleem qSnap is the querySnapshot... `qSnap.docs[0].data()` contains data of your document is it exists

Comment: its docs array is empty but there data present in firestore

Comment: @UsamaSaleem can you share a screenshot of your document in that case? Also are you passing correct values where()? `where("tokenId", "==", "TOKEN_VALUE")` tokenId is field name in the document and TOKEN_VALUE should be the value that you are looking for. If no docs are matching then there's some issue with these vaalues

Comment: yes but where i can share screenshoot

Comment: @UsamaSaleem you can edit your question and add it