# Problem while upgrading a code snippet from firebase v8 to firebase v9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to change this Firebase V8 code to Firebase V9. I have tried to change this code to v9 in several ways, but unfortunately, all of them were failure:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = db.collection("chats").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    setChats(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>({
            id:doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
           }))
        )
    );

    return unsubscribe;
}, [])
```

Comment: Also just to confirm, what is value of `db` in this code? It must be Firestore instance initialized by `getFirestore()` function.

Comment: I have initialized db in a file called `firebase.js`. In firebase.js it has been initialized with the 'getFirestore()' function.

Comment: Have you tried refactoring the code as in my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The [`collection()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#collection) and [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#onsnapshot_6) are top-level functions in Firebase v9 SDK that can be directly imported from Firestore SDK. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import { collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

useEffect(() => {
  const colRef = collection(db, "chats")

  onSnapshot(colRef, (snapshot) => {
    setChats(
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        data: doc.data(),
      }))
    )
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [])
```

Also checkout:
[Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9)

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) has examples of code written in both V8 and V9 syntax so you can just switch the tabs to [<kbd>Version 9 (Modular)</kbd>](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-version-9) and compare it with previous [<kbd>Version 8 (namespaced)</kbd>](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-version-8) syntax.

Comment: I guess the logic is ok.. The problem is how to pass the data inside the array into a component? ```{chats.map(({ id, data: { chatName }}) => ( <CustomChatList id={id} key={id} chatName={id }/> ))}``` \n but there is no chatName appearing on the screen.