# Why getting Invalid collection reference error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am updating a document in firebase when user enters a comment.The code for the same is:

```
 const docRef=collection(db,"posts",post.id);
        console.log(docRef);
        updateDoc(docRef,{
          user:localStorage.getItem('Name'),
          title: post.title,
          comment:temppost ,
          upVotesCount: 0,
          downVotesCount: 0,
          createdAt: post.createdAt,
          updatedAt: date.toUTCString(),
          isCommentVisible:false
        });
```

But  I m getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but posts/PQAvoGjUeX8aPVVZxMNC has 2.
```

I haven't used any subcollections here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) to update a single document that you can create using `doc()`. The `collection()` is used to create a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference):

```
// use doc() instead of collection()
const docRef = doc(db,"posts",post.id);
```

Also checkout: [Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9)

Comment: still the same error @Dharamaraj

Comment: @VatsalAMehta have you tried `console.log(post.id)` before that and checked if it's valid ?

Comment: it has now worked

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a document in a collection function. `(db,"posts")` is how you refer to a collection and `(db,"posts",post.id)` is how you refer to a document. So use one of these:

```
const docRef = doc(db,"posts",post.id);    // 3 arguments for a document
------
const postsRef = collection(db,"posts");   // 2 arguments for a collection
const docRef = (postsRef,post.id);         // in essence 2+1 arguments for a document
```