# Firebase - How can i get data from reference?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, reference

I have a firebase firestore with some reference datatype.

It looks like this:
[image]

[image]

I Hope, this is the correct way.

Now when i get my user from firebase, i have this reference object with the id of it.
But if i call my function to get the doc, i get an error message:

First my function and how i call it:

```js
export const getClubById = async (id: string) => {
  const doc = collection(db, 'clubs', id)
  return doc
}
```

```js
const userData = dbUser.data()
const club = await getClubById(userData.selectedClub.id)
console.log('club', club)
```

And here the error message:

```bash
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but clubs/vA7R94pX3bpHDsYIr6Ge has 2.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) already then you can use `getDoc()` function to retrieve the document from Firestore as shown below:

```
import { getDoc, DocumentReference } from "firebase/firestore";

export const getClubById = async (clubDocRef: DocumentReference) => {
  const clubSnapshot = await getDoc(clubDocRef);
  return clubSnapshot.data();
}

// Pass the reference itself to the function instead of doc ID
const club = await getClubById(userData.selectedClub)
```

---

For the error in the question, to create a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference), if you have the document ID then you should `doc()` function instead of `collection()` that is used to create a [`CollectionReferencce`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) as shown below:

```
const docRef = doc(db, 'clubs', clubID);
```

---

Also checkout: [Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9/68987445#68987445)

Comment: It worked with the getDoc function. Thanks :)