# Is there any method in the latest 9.0 version to create nested collection in firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to find a reference, but it was mostly an older version of the firestore.

```
let snapshot = await firebase.firestore()
.collection('route')
.doc('0bayKbCiAchc0Vy9XuxT')
.collection('qa')
.get()
```

Comment: Have you checked [Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68987326/13130697)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Please go through the given link for more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model.