# Fetch Single Data by Document Id Reactjs Firebase Web SDK 9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch the data from single document by selected ID. I have try with function "child" and "orderByChild" but it seems did not work with web SDK 9. Could you please to help with the new format query of web version 9.
Below is my code at table database:

```
<Link to={`/view/${id}`}>
    {id.data.dateCreate}
</Link>
```

And the code in "View" page:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
const { id } = useParams();
useEffect(() => {
    db
      .orderByChild(`reports/${id}`)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          setUser({ ...snapshot.val() });
        } else {
          setUser({});
        }
      });
  }, [id]);
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Where is `db` coming from? It should be Firestore instance  (`const db = getFirestore()`) when using my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getDoc()` function to fetch a single document as shown below:

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchDocById = async () => {
    // Create DocumentReference
    const docRef = doc(db, "reports", id) // db = getFirestore()
    
    // Fetch document
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)
    
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      setUser({
        ...snapshot.val()
      });
    } else {
      setUser({});
    }
  }

  fetchDocById()
}, [id]);
```

Also checkout: [Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9/68987445#68987445)

Comment: Thank you for your response but it still not works, it might come from the line of code <Link to={`/view/${id}`}> since the array of user has returned empty

Comment: I have fixed it. Thank you for your help. Btw, I need to change snapshot to docSnap to make it work. Anyway, thank you so much bro!