# Why am I getting TypeErrors 'x' is not a function with firebase collection query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My js file is correctly entered in the DOM, I have initailized firebase in the firebase.js file. Why am I getting a

> TypeError 'collection(...).doc is not a function' -

The collection query is taken directly from the firebase docs site, I don't understand how this could be a type error.. Any ideas?

```
import { app } from "./firebase";
import { getFirestore, doc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore(app);

// get data

const docRef = collection(db, 'posts').doc('ARt1ctrEjweKEd4gmgCr');
await docRef.get();
if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log('No such document!');
} else {
  console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doc()` is top level function in Modular SDK and not a method on `collection()`. Try:

```
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

// Creating DocumentReference
const docRef = doc(db, 'posts', 'ARt1ctrEjweKEd4gmgCr');

const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log('No such document!');
} else {
  console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
}
```

Also checkout: [Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9/68987445#68987445)

Comment: Thanks for replying Dharmaraj, is there any alternative to writing .get() function also? This is now showing as not a function after your suggestion.

Comment: @HarryNC yes, missed that! I've updated the answer. You need to use `getDoc()` function now.