# Collection references must have an odd number of segments

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently encountering this problem in my react native app using Firebase:

> Collection references must have an odd number of segments

I've seen similar cases in stackoverflow but wasn't able to solve my problem. Here is my code :

```
  const getData = async () => {
    console.log(user.uid + " ")
    const col = collection(db, "users", user.uid)
    const taskSnapshot = await getDoc(col)

    console.log(taskSnapshot)
  }

  getData()
```

I am trying to open my document with the document reference (user.uid) but I am getting this error : `Collection references must have an odd number of segments`

Hope you can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getDoc()` takes a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference.md#documentreference_class) as parameter and not a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) so you must use `doc()` instead of `collection()`.

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore" 

const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid)
const taskSnapshot = await getDoc(col)
console.log(taskSnapshot.data() || "Doc does not exists")
```

Also checkout [Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9/68987445#68987445)

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
collection(db, "users", user.uid)
```

with this

```
collection(db).document("users").collection(user.uid)
```